# Redirect to user page with PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect the users to their pages after successful log in.
Now I'm using:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/test/user.php?id='. $user);
```

and this give me this type of redirection:
"http://localhost/test/user.php?id=john"
I want my redirected URL look like this:
"http://localhost/test/user.php/john"
I've tried

```
header('Location: http://localhost/test/user.php/'. $user)
```

but it don't redirect properly.

Comment: What does "but it don't redirect properly" mean...??

Comment: I have a log out link to logout.php. when I click the link don't log me out, but send me to log out page above the user's page. It looks like this:"http://localhost/test/user.php/john/logout.php"

Comment: You need to show your code...??